# Socket Error # 13 Access denied connecting with FTP

Tags: android, delphi, ftp, indy, delphi-xe5

I am working with Embarcadero RAD Studio XE5.
I am doing FTP-Server for Android.
Used component: **IdFTPServer**.

I wrote:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Server.DefaultPort := 21;
  Server.DefaultDataPort := 21;
  Server.Active := true;
end;
```

and got error:

```
First chance exception at $546D6023. Exception class EIdSocketError with message
'Socket Error # 13
Access denied.'.
Process Project1.apk (25778)
```

How to fix this error?

I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in my XML manifest.

Comment: Are you SURE you are enabling INTERNET permission correctly? If you upgrade to the latest SVN snapshot, Indy now raises an `EIdInternetPermissionNeeded` exception when it encounters error #13 and INTERNET has not been granted ([see this](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20140314B.aspx)). What does the call stack look like when the exception is raised? Does it happen when activating the server, or when connecting a client? Why are you setting the DefaultPort and DefaultDataPort to the same port?

Comment: I wrote exactly the same server on windows, everything worked. The server will not start on adroid... Help me please!

Comment: Windows doesn't use permissions like Android does. This still looks like a permissions issue to me, that is why you need to make ABSOLUTELY SURE that your app really is running with the INTERNET permission enabled.  Remember that permissions can be isolated to specific build configurations, so make sure all of your configurations are using the same permissions.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Android runs on top of Linux. On 'Nix platforms, using ports below 1024 is restricted to system processes and root users only.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the Internet Use Permission.

Go to Project options - Uses Permissions. Check that the Release Config is selected for Android Platform.
The Internet node should be checked.
However, this is not enough (or working at all)
Now open your AndroidManifest.template.xml (NOTE!! Its the template file from your source directory)

Find : <%uses-permission%> in the file, and just below write this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You cannot just edit the AndroidManifest.xml directly in the project/Android/Release/projectName Directory as this file gets overwritten every time you compile (or build, I'm not sure)

Hope this helps you out

Regards
Jens Fudge