# How to avoid Indy Socket Error # 13 Access denied exception on Delphi and Android?

Tags: android, delphi, indy

I have exactly the same problem shown in
[Socket Error # 13 Access denied connecting with FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459737/socket-error-13-access-denied-connecting-with-ftp)

Except that the server is a `TIdSimpleServer` that the program needs to receive some files

Both
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` (just in case since AFAI it's not required to open sockets) and
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` 
are present in the template and manifest file, and also in he project permissions, but when the program reaches

```
IdSimpleServer.Port := 55; 
IdSimpleServer.Listen(20000);
```

En exception is thrown:
`Project servicios.exe raised exception class EIdSocketError with message 'Socket Error # 13 Access denied.'.`

I've deleted the `AndroidManifest.xml` to ensure it is created. It is indeed with the proper permissions. Also tried uninstalling/reinstalling, rebuilding it and rebooting. Nothing works

I´m using Delphi 10.4 on a Lenovo Tab M10 with Android 11

There is some other permission that needs to be set or a `TIdSimpleServer` property?

Comment: `I have exactly the same problem shown in` ??? Which problem?

Comment: Use a port above 1024.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android runs on top of Linux.  On 'Nix platforms, using ports below 1024 is restricted to system processes and root users only.  So, you will have to use a higher port number.

Comment: Didn't know that. Ran like charm. One important issue:  I had to bound the listening IP address to the wifi one, otherwise, the program got stuck. I guess it was bounding to the local 127.0.0.1 address